# Guardar datos en un array usando foreach loop

Tags: php, array, ciclos

De nuevo vengo a pedir ayuda, esta vez tengo que guardar los valores de una variable dentro de un array para después mostrarlos, dicha variable se encuentra dentro de un ciclo foreach, les dejo el código:

```
    $strProyecto = $conex->getIndCol('id', sqlProyectos());//proyectos válidos.
    if ($opcion3 == 'save') { 
        $proyecto_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'proyecto_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);//id del proyecto seleccionado
        if ($proyecto_id > 0) {
            $aProyecto = array("proyecto_id"=>$proyecto_id);//id del proyecto seleccionado convertido en array para que sea parámetro de getTareasPendientes
            $tareasP = Tarea::getTareasPendientes($conex, '', $aProyecto);//datos de tareas pendientes del proyecto seleccionado
            foreach ($tareasP as $ids) {
                $tarea_id = $ids['id'];
                $_Tarea = new Tarea($tarea_id, $conex);
                $_Tarea->cancelarTarea($sys_Usuario, $proyecto_id);//método para cancelar tareas pendientes
            }
        } 
    }
```

Tengo la variable `$tarea_id` que contiene el `id` de la tarea, debido a que tengo que guardar un registro en el historial tengo que hacer la cancelación tarea por tarea (`$_Tarea->cancelarTarea...`), pero para mostrar todos los `id` de las tareas que se cancelaron quiero guardarlas en un `array`para después hacer un `echo json_encode`.

Una de las opciones que vi fue algo como esto:

```
foreach($activities as $k => $v) {
    $a[] = $v['name'];
}
```

pero como utilizo `$tarea_id` en `$_Tarea = new Tarea($tarea_id, $conex);` no puedo pasarlo directamente a `array` dentro del ciclo, entonces no sé de qué manera hacerlo.

De antemano gracias(:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues seguí buscando alguna forma de resolver mi duda y me encontré con una solución, el código quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
$strProyecto = $conex->getIndCol('id', sqlProyectos());//proyectos válidos.
if ($opcion3 == 'save') { 
    $proyecto_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'proyecto_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);//id del proyecto seleccionado
    if ($proyecto_id > 0) {
        $aProyecto = array("proyecto_id"=>$proyecto_id);//id del proyecto seleccionado convertido en array para que sea parámetro de getTareasPendientes
        $aTarea = array();
        $tareasP = Tarea::getTareasPendientes($conex, '', $aProyecto);//datos de tareas pendientes del proyecto seleccionado
        foreach ($tareasP as $ids) {
            $tarea_id = $ids['id'];
            $_Tarea = new Tarea($tarea_id, $conex);
            $cancelar = $_Tarea->cancelarTarea($sys_Usuario, $proyecto_id);//método para cancelar tareas pendientes
/*Esta parte la agregué debido a otra necesidad:
            if ($cancelar == false) {
                echo "Tarea ID: $tarea_id no cancelada";
                echo "<br>";
                break;
            }
*/
            array_push($aTarea, $tarea_id);
        }
        echo 'Tareas canceladas ID: ',json_encode($aTarea);
    } 
}
```

Utilicé un `array_push` para que por cada vuelta en el ciclo me guardara al final del array el valor de `$tarea_id`.

Espero que esto pueda servirle a alguien más con un problema similar.